# Shading with Float Vector Volumes

Tags: volumetrics, fire, shader-nodes

Houdini 18.5 has a volume Bake sop that computes the internal scattering of emission based on the density. This is used to minimize the render times because the volume bounces can now be set lower and internal scattering simulated by the generated volume.

My problem is that the generated volume is a Float Vector volume. I tried using it normally as an emission strength in the Principled volume but I think this does not work because it does not take the different intensities in the different vectors into account and just multiples them and takes a general intensity. But the scattered light has a direction hence the Float Vector.

Is there a way to shade this appropriately?
[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wMObgl15S4ssPSsqfUwJFDpULtyICEcr/view?usp=sharing) is an example volume

And some screenshots of the material:
[image]
[image: i]
[image]

Comment: Okay, I added some images of my problem

Comment: Hmm… try the light ray info node?

Comment: What node do you mean? Light Path? And what would you try with them?